# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, error, modern-experience, pnpjs

I am using PnP JS in SPFx to get page content. I wanted to get content type id of the page and check if it belongs to certain content type.

I can't seem to make contain or includes function work so I have been trying to use substring to get first 44 character out so I can use it to compare but I am getting error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";

public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    
    sp.setup({
      spfxContext: this.context
    });
 
   sp.web.lists.getById(this.context.pageContext.list.id.toString())
  .items.getById(this.context.pageContext.listItem.id)
  .select("ContentTypeId")
  .get()
  .then(d=>{
    console.log(d);
    
    let content:string=d.contentTypeId
    let sitecontentid:string= "0x01100912345D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118000B8757F9909754BBB035517811AE70E"
    let contentid:string= content.substring(0,43)

    if  (contentid==sitecontent)
      
      {
        do something
        
        }

  })
 
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code inside `.then()` function:

```
let contentTypeIdString:string = d.ContentTypeId;
let siteContentTypeId:string = "0x01100912345D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118000B8757F9909754BBB035517811AE70E";

let contentTypeId:string = contentTypeIdString ? contentTypeIdString.substring(0, 43): "";

if  (contentTypeId == siteContentTypeId){
    //Your code
    console.log("Content Type Id matched.");
} else {
    console.log("Content Type Id does not match.");
}
```

Comment: It has fixed the error but it isn't bringing back any value. Is this because I have to add in await?

Comment: What data are you getting in `d` variable?

Comment: I can see in the log that it is bringing back ContentTypeId: "0x0101009D1CB255DA76424F860D91F20E6C4118000B5BA1CF9909754BBB035517811AE70E0069911E447514314B86BB32EBE555E9EC"
but I have put alert that displays the value after `let contentTypeId:string = contentTypeIdString ? contentTypeIdString.substring(0, 43): "";`
and it just comes up blank.

Comment: Above code should work for you for this response. I see above content type id does not match with your `siteContentTypeId`. So, it will not execute `if` block. Try using updated code in my answer OR adding breakpoint at the line `let contentTypeId:string =` & see if brings the response correctly.

Comment: Thanks,@ganesh-sanap it is working now. I had `let content:string=d.contentTypeId` the C in contentTypeId should have been capital. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Yes, I observed that initially from your question & that's why I send you the complete code in my answer. Anyways, glad it worked for you!